# LINQ: "Types in Union or Concat are constructed incompatibly."

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, notsupportedexception

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET and LINQ but I encountered a very strange behaviour that is nearly driving me crazy. I found a few discussions about the error mentioned in the title, but none seemed to fit my problem. Please have a look at the following snapshot from the Object Relational Designer:

[image: Screenshot from ORD, showing the data model]

As you can see, a `Relation` stands for the connection of two `Anchor`s. So for this there are two foreign keys defined for table `Relation`: `Relation.AnchorIDFrom => Anchor.AnchorID` and `Relation.AnchorIDTo => Anchor.AnchorID`. None of those columns is nullable. My goal now is, given a list of IDs of anchors, to retrieve all `Relation`s any of these anchors participates in. Here's the method for this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetRelations(String token, List<Guid> anchorIDs)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    LinkItCoreDataContext dc = new LinkItCoreDataContext();

    IQueryable relationQry =
        from anchor in dc.Anchors
        where anchorIDs.Contains(anchor.AnchorID)
        //stupid names because object relational designer
        //does not seem to support custom names:
        from relation in anchor.Relations.Union(anchor.Relations1)
        select new
        {
            relationID = relation.RelationID,
            anchorIDFrom = relation.AnchorIDFrom,
            anchorIDTo = relation.AnchorIDTo,
            relationTypes = from type in relation.RelationTypes
                            //stupid names again:
                            select type.RelationType1
        };
    return js.Serialize(relationQry);//Here's where the error occurs
}
```

At runtime this gives me a `NotSupportedException` stating **Types in Union or Concat are constructed incompatibly**. I think this is quite weird, because the expression `anchor.Relations.Union(anchor.Relations1)` should merge two things that are fully equal in a syntactical sense. If I change the critical line to `from relation in anchor.Relations` or `from relation in anchor.Relations1` everything works fine. Also, adding `ToList()` (which is sometimes mentioned as solution) does not change anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835649/strange-linq-to-sql-union-error

Comment: I know that question. As I have mentioned above, none of the participating columns are nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a similar case and get the same error while in Entity Framework exactly the same query runs fine. So I think you're running into a bug here (or an "unsupported feature") and you may have to work around it. You could do that by turning the query around:

```
var relationQry =
      from relation in anchor.Relations
      where anchorIDs.Contains(relation.AnchorIDTo) 
         || anchorIDs.Contains(relation.AnchorIDFrom)
      select new
      {
          relationID = relation.RelationID,
          anchorIDFrom = relation.AnchorIDFrom,
          anchorIDTo = relation.AnchorIDTo,
          relationTypes = from type in relation.RelationTypes
                          select type.RelationType1
      };
```

By the way: you can change the "stupid names" :) by selecting the association in the designer and the names of its child property.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.
Eventually I solved this.

It appears that even when the resulting types are equal, using nested relations will
cause errors.

What I did to solve this problem was:

I defined DataLoadOptions as such:

```
var lo = new DataLoadOptions();

lo.LoadWith<Type>(t => t.NESTEDTYPE); // "t" is the database object in this scenario.
lo.LoadWith<Type>(t => t.NESTEDTYPE2);
lo.LoadWith<Type>(t => t.NESTEDTYPE3);

// etc.

dc.LoadOptions = lo;
```

For each nested type you have to specify a loadwith.
You can only assign Loadoptions **once** on each "alive" datacontext.

I hope with this you will be able to resolve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
from relation in anchor.Relations.Concat(anchor.Relations1)
```

or

```
from relation in anchor.Relations.Concat(anchor.Relations1).Distinct()
```

This 2nd should be functionally the same as Union, but I'm not convinced it is what you want, if it is it might give a better error message.

Comment: I tried both apporaches. Unfortunately - they don't make a difference.

Comment: As I wrote, there's no difference. And that means: Same error.